# Scraping text from a <span> from <span> but both have inner text

Tags: python, web-scraping

this is the html tags i want get text from its span

```
<span class="ms-2 d-flex">
     <span class="d-none d-xl-block me-1"> mobile </span>   
     ItsMobileNumber
</span>
```

so its one main span with span and some text 'ItsMobileNumber'
i want get the 'ItsMobileNumber' but when i use `get_text()` it getting both text like this :

```
mobile
ItsMobileNumber
```

and this is my python code

```
print(title.find("span").get_text())
```

how can i get just 'ItsMobileNumber' not inner span text ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried this?:

```
data = title.find("span").get_text()
number = [d.text for d in data]
```

Or,

```
import re
number = re.findall("[0-9]+",data)
```

If you want the main span as well, you can do:

```
main = data.contents[0]
```

Comment: thx but umm i don't want remove text or just get number for example if text of main span was string and the inner span text was string too , how can get main span text

Comment: @sajjadaskari - You can do `main = data.contents[0]`.

Comment: it worked on data.contents[2] thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
soup = bs([your html file],'lxml')

data = soup.select("span.ms-2.d-flex")
for datum in data:
    print(list(datum.strings)[2].strip())
```

The output, based only on your sample html, should be

```
ItsMobileNumber
```